# Android: Keep running app in the background

Tags: android

In my app when i exit from app it does not running in the background and close completely but i want app keep running in the background, How can i do it?

this my code:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setTitle("Exit")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Service to run application in background:

> A Service is an application component that can perform long-running operations in the background and does not provide a user
>   interface

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: can you help me that i use what?

Comment: please learn about Service and try to implement it . Stack-overflow is not place to help code. try to implement it , if you are face any problem then ask question. any one help you to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the sample code below

```
public class BackHelper extends Service {

   private static final String TAG = "me.trial";
   @Override
   public void onCreate()
  {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onCreate" );
         super .onCreate();
         new sock().call();
  }
   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onDestroy" );
         super .onDestroy();
  }
   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onstart" );

         return Service.START_STICKY;
  }
   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onBind" );
         return null ;
  }

}
```

Call the service from your activity like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, BackHelper.class);    
startService(intent);
```

Also add

`<service android:name=".BackHelper" />`

Within the manifest

`<application />` tag

Comment: What you meant by not true?

Comment: when i add this code in intelij have some error , for example error to onCreate() and others

Comment: You should import its headers, use shortcut `cntrl + shift + o`